# How can i get remaining rows after inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables

1.Applicants table(id , name)

2.posts table(id , post_name ,applicant_id)

If i do inner join, I will get applicants who are having posts ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`applicant_id` = `applicants`.`id` ).

Now what i need to do for getting applicants who are not having any posts.

Comment: if you could read [THIS POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) I wrote on how to write better questions it would be helpful and we can give you a tested answer that works

Answer (score 2):

You need both an `outer join` and the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT
      a.id
    , COUNT(p.applicant_id) post_count
FROM applicants a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p
                  ON a.id = p.applicant_id
GROUP BY
      a.id
HAVING COUNT(p.applicant_id) = 0
```

Actually you don't need a group by and this would be sufficient:

```
SELECT
      a.id
FROM applicants a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p
                  ON a.id = p.applicant_id
WHERE p.applicant_id IS NULL
```

Comment: unless there are multiple ids and the OP wants a count per applicant of their number of posts.

Comment: requirement is: `getting applicants ... not having any posts` : so there is nothing to count

Comment: :) it happens - i'm getting wee bit tired of nothing getting accepted as answer... my beef for the day

Comment: just as a note for the OP if there are more than one application  that an applicant can apply for then you may want to keep the group by in there to remove duplicates

Comment: you know what I totally missed that in my how to ask post.. I think I'll add that as a side note :) if you wanna read it its in the comment to this question

Answer (score 0):

If you need applicants without post then you need this

```
SELECT
      a.* 
FROM applicants a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p
                  ON a.id = p.applicant_id
WHERE p.applicant_id IS NULL
```

When you have to show applicants having post then you need to change LEFT OUTER JOIN to  INNER  JOIN .

And if you need both don't care post of applicant then left join will works for you

```
SELECT
          a.*,p.* 
    FROM applicants a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p
                      ON a.id = p.applicant_id
```

**NOTE:**- * must be change with column name for best practise.

Comment: What i copied , i just explain little more .

Comment: It is because the alias names are same and it always be the better approach when we need applicant whose posts are not defined .

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select a.id,count(p.applicant_id) 
from applicants a left outer join posts p
ON a.id=p.applicant_id
where p.post_name is null
group by a.id
```